# Possible to create and switch between views/configurations of a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to save different configurations of a pivot table and easily switch between them? For example, one configuration that has certain values along the X and Y axes, another configuration that has different values, etc.

Comment: I don't think so.  The normal way to do something like this is with `Custom Views`.  They can store filter settings but do not seem to affect the Pivot Table fields.

Answer (score 0):

Create two pivot tables, on two sheets, and switch between the sheets. That can easily be done with hyperlinks, without code. The two pivot tables will use the same pivot cache, so workbook performance will not be impacted.